# Repair ext4 filesystem on USB drive

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, ext4

Yet another filesystem question. I wanted to use a USB drive that I hadn't mounted for a month or so and was surprised by the fact Ubuntu was unable to mount it. I looked it up in the disk utility and it said it discovered a device with 17 MB instead of 2 GB. The hardware looks intact, I hope for the best for repairing the ext4 filesystem.
I followed the instructions from [HOWTO: Repair a broken Ext4 Superblock in Ubuntu](http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/), but I wasn't successful.

```
# fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdb
```

> e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
>   ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
>   fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
>   fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb
>
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
>   filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
>   filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
>   is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
>       e2fsck -b 8193

Filesystem blocks are invalid, however when I run the recommended solution to try the alternate superblock, I get the following output:

```
# e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/sdb
```

> e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
>   e2fsck: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sdb

plus the same error message as in the last paragraph above.
Any ideas how to recover the drive?
Thank you very much!

---

Edit: `testdisk` won't help. I'm still stunned why the tools only discover 17 MB.

---

The gparted feature "Attempt Data Rescue" yielded no results, no filesystems were identified.

---

*@Colin* According to disc utility, the device is unpartitioned, I can only deal with devices at the moment. It's the question if the partition table *or* the filesystem is damaged. Running fsck with partition gives

> fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sdb1
>   Possibly non-existent device?

---

*@John*

```
# sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1 | hd
```

> 00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
>   *
>   1+0 records in
>   1+0 records out
>   512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.00307007 s, 167 kB/s
>   00000200

<strike>Since all are zeros, this means no remains of MBR?</strike>

The result was there quite quick.

```
sudo hd /dev/sdb | less
```

> 00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
>   *
>   01000000

It's all zero. I guess the pendrive broke down lying in a drawer in a magical, unexplainable way.

Comment: Create a new partition table.

Comment: How can I do it? Will I possibly keep the data?

Comment: Sorry you will loose your data if you create a new partition table. As I know, unlike NTFS, ext4 doesn't get damage unless your device is. ext4 is not focused as a filesystem for pen drivers. Most pen drivers are optimized to support FAT. You can create a new partition table using the **Disk Utility** in Ubuntu...but I can't confirm it will fix your issue. For me, it did.

Comment: If you think it had been partitioned to begin with, utilities aren't going to make up for the lack of partitioning now. In that case I suggest you include in your question a link to the output of `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1 | hd` to see if there is a remnant of an MBR there.

Comment: No remants of an MBR. Is the whole thing zeros? `sudo hd /dev/sdb | less` If it is all zeros it will take a long time to read the whole thing to tell you that.

Comment: @JohnSGruber I edited the question. I'm afraid there will be no real answer to this question because of hardware failure.

Comment: @Naveen I tried to create a new partition table with disk utility. It took a while and then gave up: `Error creating partition table: helper exited with exit code 1: Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdb: Input/output error`

Comment: It definitely sounds like a hardware problem to me.